# Is it possible to inspect ember data model from a controller?

Tags: ember-data

Is it possible to get the list of attributes from Ember Data model inside a controller based on model name.

I have 1 select box, where model can be chosen and now I need another select box, where model fields can be selected.

I have tried this:

```
this.store.modelFor('customer').attributes
```

But it looks like attributes are missing (i'm probably doing it wrong :-)

Is there any way I can get the attributes?

Thanks
/AK